# Jersey JAX-RS and OpenaAPI deepObject = true deserialization problem

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, deserialization, openapi, json-api

**We have problems deserializing a query parameter with square bracket notation (`?paging[offset]=3`) in Jersey.**

We're using Jersey JAX-RS and annotating our endpoints and beans with swagger OpenAPI, and have tooling to generate our documentation automatically. We want to follow the `JSON:API` standard for describing a new API. `JSON:API` specifies that to implement paging, the API must accept a **query parameter** in the format : `?paging[offset]=0&paging[limit]=10`

Our swagger annotations support this out of the box, allowing us to specify

```
@Parameter(
description = "paging",
style = ParameterStyle.DEEPOBJECT,
explode = Explode.TRUE)
```

Which is compatible with the square bracket notation `paging[offset]` and so on. And it generates the correct documentation for our `paging` parameter. All is good and great and dandy.

JAX-RS is the problem. There's a `@QueryParam` annotation in JAX-RS. But, to use a complex object with the `@QueryParam` annotation, that type must have `a constructor with a single String parameter`. No problem. Let's add a constructor to our paging bean.

```
public class PagingBean {

  public PagingBean(String stringValue){...}

  @XmlElement
  public getOffset(){...}
  public setOffset(int offset){...}

  @XmlElement
  public getLimit(){...}
  public setLimit(int limit){....}

}
```

So our endpoint now looks like

```
@Get("/path")
public Response someEndpoint(
  @Parameter(description = "paging",style = ParameterStyle.DEEPOBJECT,explode = Explode.TRUE) @QueryParam("paging") PagingBean paging
){
...
}
```

But if we hit our api with

`GET /rest/path?paging[limit]=10&paging[offset]=5`

We can see that the `paging` request parameter is null. It seems like Jersey didn't even recognize that the `paging[...` is part of the `paging` `QueryParam`. Probably that it expects exactly the `paging` key, and not a `paging\[?`-like key.

We can confirm this by injecting a `@Context UriInfo ui` and checking the request parameters. Their key are `paging[offset]` and `paging[limit]`

One solution to this is to `flatten` our parameters in the endpoint like so

```
@QueryParam("paging[limit]") pagingLimit,
@QueryParam("paging[offset]") pagingOffset
```

But this is not very nice to look at.

Ideas on how to deserialize this in Jersey ?

Comment: Jersey's `@QueryParam` does not recognize deep-object parameters. But it is possible to register your own annotation to handle this. Take a look at this excellent answer by Paul Samsotha: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66426398/106350